# Can't get a decimal number from json decode

Tags: php, json

Using this php file:

```
$value = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?  country=US&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=Souvenir%20UMP- 45%20%7C%20Fallout%20Warning%20%28Factory%20New%29');
 $obj = json_decode($value);
$keys = $obj->lowest_price * 2;
```

I'm trying to use a decimal number to fill my equation but so for $obj->lowest_price gets me an integer number and I think that's because the json gives me "36,19€" (it returns 36) and that symbol makes that problem.

How can I put the decimal number in the equation?

Comment: Show us a sample return value and parse value

Comment: Try parsing it through `NumberFormatter::parseCurrency( ... )` to convert it from a currency string to a float before attempting any calculations : http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php

Comment: This is what enters in the ecuation 36,19€ and that's what comes out: 72

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast your value as float so it also retrieves the decimals even if it founds a currency symbol afterward.

However, it requires that the number is formed with a dot, and not with a comma, so you will have to replace it :

```
$value = '33,22€';
echo (float) str_replace(',', '.', $value) * 2;
```

Output :

`66.44`

(You can change it again to replace the dot by a comma as it was in the beginning by the way)

Comment: ... and hope it's never a product with a value over € 10.000,00 (for example) - nl_NL currency format.

Comment: @CD001 Right, but it's unlikely to happen on Steam though. ;) Using a formatter is safer for sure, as long as you have PECL